# How to pass options to ListPlot when using a DataSet?

Tags: dataset, plotting

Still learning the new `DataSet` feature, I would like to create a `ListPlot` where the color of the points is to be determined by a column in the dataset. Here is what I have:

```
(* import and set column names *)
iris = SemanticImport["http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/data/iris.csv"];
iris = iris[All, <|
    "SepalLength" -> 1, "SepalWidth" -> 2, 
    "PetalLength" -> 3, "PetalWidth" -> 4, "Species" -> 5
|>] 

(* ListPlot *)
iris[ListPlot, {"PetalLength", "SepalWidth"}]
```

Now I have no idea how to set the color according the "Species" column. The documentation did not help. Ideally, the plot has a legend mapping colors to species.

Any hint appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
color[s_] := Switch[s, "setosa", Red, "versicolor", Green, "virginica", Blue];
iris[ListPlot[Style[{#,#2},color@#3]&@@@#,
              BaseStyle->{PointSize[.015] ,FontSize->16},
              PlotLabel->"Iris Data"]&, 
 {"PetalLength", "SepalWidth","Species"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Great solution!

Comment: @KarstenW., thank you for the Accept.

Comment: Great code. I am using a lot and would like to add a tooltip for each point which displays the values {x,y} but does not succeed to. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Porty thank you for kind words. I am not able to test but doesn't `iris[ListPlot[Style[Tooltip[{#, #2}], color @ #3]&@@@# , ... ]` work?

Answer (score 11):

```
ListPlot[iris[GroupBy[Key["Species"]],All,{"PetalLength", "SepalWidth"}],
   PlotLegends -> "Expressions" ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found a solution to my question.

```
color[s_] := Switch[s, "setosa", Red, "versicolor", Green, "virginica", Blue];
ListPlot[
    List /@ Normal@iris[All, {"SepalLength", "PetalWidth"}],
    PlotStyle -> Normal@(color /@ iris[All, "Species"]),
    PlotLegends -> SwatchLegend @@ 
          Transpose[({color[#], #} & /@ iris[Union, "Species"])]
]
```

However, if you have a more `Query`ish answer, I will upvote and accept yours...