# Operator form for Histogram of multiple datasets?

Tags: dataset, operators, query

I would like to plot a histogram for multiple datasets in a dataset query, but can't quite seem to make it work in operator notation:

```
titanic = ExampleData[{"Dataset", "Titanic"}];
titanic = Dataset@Flatten@Table[
     Map[Append[#, "score" -> RandomReal[100]] &, Normal@titanic], 
     20];

(*this ugly version works:*)
Histogram @ Transpose[List @@@ titanic[Slice[All, {"age", "score"}]] // Normal]

(*but the operator forms version does not:*)
titanic[Histogram, Slice[All, {"age", "score"}]]
titanic[Slice[All, {"age", "score"}] /* Histogram]
```

[image]

How to do this with just operator forms?

Comment: What is the `Slice` function?

Comment: It's in GeneralUtilities

Comment: Also note that `Transpose@
 titanic[Transpose /* 
   Query[<|#, "score" -> RandomReal[{0, 100}, 1309]|> &]]` is a more efficient addition of `"score"`.

Comment: closely related: [How to pass options to ListPlot when using a DataSet?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/63879/125)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use [`Composition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Composition.html) with [`Transpose`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose.html).

```
titanic[Histogram@*Transpose, {"age", "score"}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope this helps.